# Sending large ammount of data with USB

Tags: stm32, serial, ftdi

I'm currently facing a big problem.
I've an MCU (STM32L4) connected to an SD card (SDIO) which stores tons of data (5Gb) from a microphone. I need to send this data as fast as possible from SD card to my PC.
With a serial port this is to slow, since the max baud rate of my MCU is 115kb/s.
How can I solve this? I'm thinking about using an FTDI module but for what I'm reading the speed is always limited by MCU baud rate.
Best Regards

Comment: Why not remove the SD card and connect to PC? Does the STM32L4 you use have USB? MCU may not the limit, FTDI modules can be, depending on which you use - Which FTDI module do you mean? Why is the MCU limited to 115200, why can't you change it?

Comment: You can't unplug the SD card and insert it into the computer? Is your 32L4 one of the ones with USB or USB OTG?

Comment: 32L4 family has MCUs with USB support. Maybe you should pick one of those so that you are not limited to the baudrate of FTDI/UART.

Comment: Miguel, it appears you are using the really-simple-to-use (but not so fast) virtual COM port HID support driver that is ubiquitous on PCs over USB connections. That's not ever going to be fast and it is probably mediated by a separate chip on your MCU board that you have NO CONTROL over. You'll need a direct USB connection and you'll need to write (or find) software drivers for BOTH SIDES of the wire to get high speed over USB. You are entering *difficult* territory now. For example: [PIC18F4XJ5X Full-Speed USB Demonstration Board](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51806b.pdf).

Comment: @jonk thank you. My MCU already has USB peripheral but its max speed is 12Mbit/s. So are you sugesting me to change the MCU?

Comment: @RonBeyer it doens't have OTG. If it has OTG would help? Thank you

Comment: @RohatKılıç my MCU has USB but the USB max speed is 12Mbit/s

Comment: @MiguelAndrade No, USB Full-Speed is the fastest supported on that processor. 12Mb/sec is probably the fastest data transfer rate you'll be able to hope for. Unless you want to change processors you'll probably be stuck at that speed as your maximum.

Comment: @MiguelAndrade What I understand from your writing so far is that you are using an async peripheral to talk with the PC. If so, you are using a standard already-existing HID driver on the PC designed for what is called a virtual COM port. However, a virtual COM port, while already supported on the PC by its existing drivers, cannot be supported on your MCU board without a matching set of driver software. Since you seem focused upon "baud rates" (actually BPS), this implies to me that you are ignorant of these details and are just using your MCU's "serial port" peripheral.

Comment: @MiguelAndrade The only way that works is if there is ANOTHER chip on your MCU board which mediates between your "serial port" and the actual USB connection to the PC. It is this other chip that is your problem. That said, your MCU might actually include a full speed USB port capability. But it is clear you are not using it, from your description. So my point to you is to find some other MCU board which DOES SUPPORT a high speed USB connection and does NOT have another chip that is STANDING IN YOUR WAY. Perhaps your board allows you to achieve it. If so, you need to stop using the async port.

Comment: @MiguelAndrade I don't know about the STM32L4, personally. And I've not looked over the datasheet. And besides, I know nothing about the board you are using. I'm just speaking in a generic way. If you have an MCU that supports a high speed (USB 2.0, let's say, for now) connection to the PC and its USB peripheral and external circuitry is set up correctly, then you will need a driver running on your MCU that will operate it in high speed mode, plus you will need a matching driver on the PC side that works with your MCU driver, properly.

Comment: @MiguelAndrade Sometimes, you can "cheat" and find a PC-side high speed driver that has already been written and you can make use of. If so, you will need to understand that driver's requirements, in intimate detail, and then make sure that the driver you write (or secure) for your MCU side works well with it. It's possible that ST itself provides such drivers for you, for both sides of the wire. But it seems very clear to me that you are not using them, right now, since you are limited to what appears to be a max async rate (115 kbps) and not a high speed USB 2.0 rate of 12 Mbps.

Comment: @MiguelAndrade Could just be my own confusion. Let me know more about what you are doing to clarify my ignorance, if so. After reading my errors handed to me by you, I'll just gladly delete my comments as unhelpful, then.

Comment: @jonk I really appreciate your help. You are right. I'm using an UART to serial converter (CP2102). For what I'm seeing STM USB does not support more than 12Mb/s. I'm so sad. I've invested a lot of time to learn STM's MCUs and I really don't want to change.

Comment: @MiguelAndrade If I'm reading [that chip](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/CP2102-9.pdf) datasheet correctly, it's strictly an async connection to your STM device and it supports, at max, 921600 bps. And that assumes a lot in terms of your MCU board design, as well. None of which I'm in any way sure of. So the actual limit rate may be what you wrote: 115 kbps. That chip ***uses*** a high speed mode, at 12 Mbps, to talk with the PC. But that does NOT mean it supports even that much. In fact, it supports less than a tenth that much. You are way out of your depth, I fear.

Comment: @MiguelAndrade The fact that the datasheet calls out support for a high speed USB 2.0, 12 Mbps mode of operation does not in any way suggest that it extends that full capability to your MCU. That just means that it will talk with the HID driver on the PC with that high speed mode. All that does is shorten the time it requires to bother the PC with some data. It doesn't mean ***your MCU*** can access it. To your MCU, it extends an async interface. So it uses a high speed mode to talk to the PC and a low speed mode to talk to your MCU. You are stuck.

Comment: @MiguelAndrade If you want serious speed you will be moving into USB 3.x and, even then, what you can actually achieve will depend a great deal on your skillsets with USB. Obviously, these skills are currently at a very low level (you have left all of the serious learning and hard work to other people, so far.) So this means not only do you need to catch up with USB 2.0 (starting point), you will then need to educate yourself on USB 3.x, as well. Much more work! You can hire this out if you need it done. Or just buy something, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

If you clock the STM32 with a 64MHz clock and use the over-sample by 8 mode then you can get up to 8Mbps data rates just using the UART.

The FTDI cables support data rates much faster than 115200 bps.  In some cases you may have to use the D2XX drivers instead of the COM port drivers.

**TTL-232RG-VREG3V3-WE**
3.3V TTL UART, up to 3Mbps baud rate.
https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm

NOTE:  Due to 128 byte RX buffer and 1kHz USB full-speed frame timing.  Sustained transfer rate is limited to 1kHz * 128 bytes * 8 bits/Byte = 1.024,Mbps.

**C232HD-DDHSP-0**
3.3V TTL UART, up to 12Mbps baud rate.
https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBMPSSE.htm

NOTE:  Due to 1K byte RX buffer and 8kHz USB hi-speed frame timing.  Sustained transfer rate is limited to 8kHz * 1K bytes * 8 bits/Byte = 8.192 Mbps.

**C232HM-DDHSL-0**
3.3V TTL UART, up to 30Mbps
https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBMPSSE.htm

NOTE:  Due to 1K byte RX buffer and 8kHz USB hi-speed frame timing.  Sustained transfer rate is limited to 8kHz * 1K bytes * 8 bits/Byte = 8.192 Mbps.

Comment: But FTDI module amplifies that 115200bps rate?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "amplifies".  The FTDI module and the MCU need to be set at the same baud rate.  Obviously it can't take or put data faster than the interface on the MCU side.  But on the STM32 the hardware limit seems to be 8Mbps, unless you are using a transceiver or a clock source that imposes a lower limit.

Comment: Please note that FTDI has a FIFO that may limit the transfer rate. Even if the FT232RL cable can use 3 Mbps baud rate, it has a 256 and 128 byte RX and TX FIFOs. As USB scheduling with 12Mbps USB peripherals works at about 1ms or 1000Hz rate, it means continuous data flow at 3Mbps is impossible and depending on direction only up to 2.56 Mbps and 1.28 Mbps is achievable.

Comment: Why assuming only "full speed" instead of "high speed" USB? I justed measured with a FT2232H mini module the continous rate and the result is ~1.200000 words per second (if 12000000 baud rate is set). A word is 8 data bits + 1 start bit + 1 stop bit. So the 12 Mbps are exactly reached and sustained over long periods. The FT232H is afaik basicially the same only with one port and the C232HM and C232HD are both based on the FT232H. TL;DR if the USB is not artifically slowed down the FTs deliver the promised data rate to the best of my knowledge and test. Or did I miss anything?

Comment: @ChristianB.  That's good to know about the FT232H.  I did assume USB Hi-Speed.  Thats why you see an 8KHz micro-frame timing in the calculation.  But I still only got about 1.024 million bytes per second in the calculation.  It would be interesting to know what they are doing in the driver to get the full data rate.  FYI, I have also run tests on some of their RS485 cables that advertised 3Mbps, and I got the full 3Mbps sustained rate out of them also.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this "as fast as possible" you should either move the card to a reader in a PC, or embed a USB SD reader and a USB mux.  Your MCU can access the card through the mux and reader, and then when unnecessary unmount the filesystem, flip the mux switch, and expose the card as USB mass storage at the full hardware speed.   This isn't an original idea - some smartphone card readers do exactly this only using a Linux WiFi SoC (instead of MCU) to provide one access mode while USB provides the other.

Or you could implement USB mass storage in your MCU, but that's going to be slower, not just because you'll be at a lower USB bandwidth but because you may not have sufficient buffer memory to sustain what the bus could move.

Consider what read speed the card can support in a reader on a PC, you won't get faster than that, so pick an approach that isn't too much worse.